# android: video capturing on device or emulator

Tags: android, video, capture

is it possible to capture what's going on in an android screen as video, either on the device itself or the emulator?

thanks!

Comment: For device you have inbuilt command from Kitakt ApI 19. Do `adb shell` and then -> `screenrecord /sdcard/test.mp4` -> `Ctrl-C` when done.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use one of the many screencast webapps - I personally use http://screenr.com/ and http://www.screentoaster.com/ - they're both quite easy to use and work under win, osx and linux. Screentoaster support uploading to youtube too. It's possible to confine the recording area so that it just captures the emulator's display.

The only downside is that I haven't been able to find a screencast webapp that hides the mouse cursor.

**Edit:** Apparently ScreenR is osx and win only.

Answer (score 2):

You can take screenshots via DDMS, but I belive to record video off the emulator you will have to use something else, I personally use [Jing](http://www.techsmith.com/jing/) and then just edit the video. To take screenshots of a real device it needs to be rooted, im guessing video capture requires it too.

Comment: A correction about screenshots: some devices with Android 2.3 (at least) support screenshots natively, to take one you have to press Power+Home. I've seen it on Samsung Galaxy S2 and LG Optimus. And in ICS this was added to Android itself. The support I've seen on 2.3 lacks one thing though: you can't take a shot while holding down some button on the screen.

Comment: This is correct, when I posted my answer 2.3 wasnt on the map. Thanks for the correction

Comment: Nice software jing good ui and quick

Answer (score 2):

This Free Screen Video Recorder is also ok: http://www.dvdvideosoft.com/products/dvd/Free-Screen-Video-Recorder.htm