# android - How to shoot the video using emulator properties

Tags: android-emulator

My Application is running in emulator at that time i want to video shoot the emulator screen using the
emulator properties(means without using any external devices like camera). I don't know how to do it. is it possible? if yes then how to do it. otherwise give me the reason why it is not possible. if any other alternatives are there. please provide if any . can anybody help me.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the very simple way! A screen recorder
[android: video capturing on device or emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4246548/android-video-capturing-on-device-or-emulator)

If you want to use the phone instead of the emulator
then i suggest you connect a video out and record the stream on a computer.

Comment: hi, in this recorder maximum time is 5mins. But i need more time how to change the settings. and how to save the record video into our local path.

Comment: just search on the net for video capturing software.. A very very good one is camtasia screen recorder.. The best thing you can do is search for a free one out there. there are dozens

Comment: means it is  not possible to get more than 5min in screenr. and more thing after i am clicking on done button in screenr i am getting the ssl connection error. and how to save that recorded video.