# how to record video of my application screen programmatically in android

Tags: android, android-video-player

I am developing Android application. In my application, I have to capture a screen animation for few seconds as video in programmatically. Is it possible?  When I Googled all the code are for starting camera in video mode or capture the system screen as video.

I need to record my application screen alone when I run in emulator or device and I have to store in video format in SDCard and later to play the video as needed.

Can anyone say is it possible in programmatically?  if so please say how to do it. if not, give some suggestion for doing this task.

Comment: Till now i didnt get solution. Does any one know solution?please help me. Is there any api in core java for above question?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4246548/android-video-capturing-on-device-or-emulator

Check the accepted answer for 2 links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I built an app and wanted to demo it for a large group of people at work. I bought [Screencast](http://www.androidcentral.com/android-app-review-screen-cast-screen-recorder) to make the recording. This app only works on rooted phones. Nonetheless, it proves it is possible to do what you want. If nothing else, I suppose you could [call the app from inside your app using an intent.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728465/how-to-call-one-android-application-from-another-android-application)